# Inequality in excel fails at equality

Tags: excel, excel-formula, inequality, vba

The following line in my spreadsheet fails:

```
Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR(ABS(F21-B21)>C21+0.0001,F21=""""),""NG"","""")"
```

I am comparing two numbers and when F21-B21 = C21 then the following code shows NG. The addition of 0.0001 is meant to mitigate this error, however it does not work.

I believe this is because Excel may be looking at C21 not as an exact number (i.e. 0.08) but rather as 0.0834892379 or some other long string of numbers.

Is this possible? Alternatively, what else can be wrong? If any other information is required, please let me know.

The inequality I want to check is:

ABS(F21-B21) >= C21

M.W.

Comment: Put in the formula `=C21-0.08` and see what the result is.

Comment: The number's I am comparing have resolution to the hundredths place, so the largest epsilon I can add is 0.009 without changing the result.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. If you believe `C21` contains `0.08` put in a formula in another cell to compute the difference between `C21` and `0.08` and that should tell you how close the value of `C21` is to `0.08`, from your question the answer would be `0.0034892379`.

Answer (score 2):

To test if two values are equal with-in an epsilon value, you can subtract the values and then compare them to the epsilon:

```
Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR(ABS(F21-B21-C21)<0.0001,F21=""""),""NG"","""")"
```

If you meant to test whether `ABS(F21-B21)` equals `C21` instead, use

```
Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR(ABS(ABS(F21-B21)-C21)<0.0001,F21=""""),""NG"","""")"
```

To compare if ABS(F21-B21) >= C21 within an epsilon, you can compare the difference to the negative epsilon:

```
Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR((ABS(F21-B21)-C21)>=-0.0001,F21=""""),""NG"","""")"
```

Alternatively, you could round the result. For example, to test if it is >=C21 within 5 decimal places:

```
Cells(21, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR(ROUND(ABS(F21-B21),5)>=C21,F21=""""),""NG"","""")"
```

Comment: If you're taking the absolute value of the difference in those three numbers, won't the inequality always come up as false? Shouldn't the inequality be the other direction?

Comment: No, try some samples. If F21 = 200, B21 = 100, C21 = 100,  then F21-B21 = 100, F21-B21-C21 = 0 and 0 < 0.0001. If F21 = 100, B21 = 200, C21 = -100, then F21-B21 = -100, F21-B21-C21 = 0, 0 < 0.0001, and so on. However, if F21 = 100, B21 = 200, C21 = 100, then F21-B21 = -100, F21-B21-C21 = -200 and ABS(-200) = 200 which is not < 0.0001 and is false. So the first example if to test for F21-B21 = C21.

Comment: I don't want to check for equality. I want to check whether the difference between F21 and B21 is greater than or equal to C21. So if F21 = 2.08 and B21 = 2.03 and C21 = 0.08 then I want the cell with the formula to be equal to "". However, in your equality it would flag it as NG.

Comment: I see, didn't see the addition. I updated my answer to handle `>=` with epsilon.